# Accessing an object declared in parent class in PHP

Tags: php

Edit: Original example removed as it was complex.

The codes provided below doesn't work. I am trying to access the methods defined in a class which is declared in the parent class.

Here is a sample code. Its not working and I'd like to know why

```
<?php
function & get_instance()
{
    return Main::get_instance();
}


class Db{

    function select($var)
    {
        echo $var; 
    }
}

class Main
{
    public $db ;
    public $process ;
    private static $instance;

    function __construct()
    {
        self::$instance = &$this;

        $this->db = new Db ; 
        $this->process = Process; 

    }

    public static function & get_instance()
    {
        return self::$instance;
    }

}


class Process{

private $main ; 
    function __construct()
    {
        $this->main = get_instance() ; 
    }

    function processPayment()
    {
        $this->main->db->select("hello");
    }
}




$main = new Main ;

$main->process->processPayment();
```

Comment: why not just have your payments constructor call the main constructor?

Comment: Yep, have the child call the parent constructor. Unless you don't need to do anything in the child constructor in which case you can leave it out and it will default to the parent constructor. Anytime you declare a child constructor that needs to do something in the parent constructor you must call it yourself with `parent::__construct()`.

Comment: what a mixture of vars, no-accessor-specified methods and static methods...

Answer (score 1):

To access members of a parent class, you will have to declare those members `protected` or `public`.

For example:

```
public var $db; 
protected var $orders;
```

Comment: It is declared as public already. Its just that I didn't include it here in this sample code

Comment: @getvivekv then it is already accessible. Just use `$this->db` in the extended class

Comment: It is not accessible in the child class. $db in defined as public in the Main class however, if I call $this->db->select() then php will through error Fatal error: Call to a member function from() on a non-object in ...

Comment: I tried this. And this calls the constructor of the parent function and the parent function construct declares  the  child class function and it is going infinite loop until php gets timed out

Comment: @getvivekv that doesn't mean it is not accessible. It means it has not been set!

Comment: @getvivekv I didn't spot that yet :) ... so the super class contains an instance of the sub class? interesting

Comment: Yes, because I am trying to make it in such as way that the Main class holds all other sub classes and I need to call like $main->order->function1(), $main->order->function2(), $main->db->select() etc

Comment: @getvivekv but then why is order even inheriting from Main ? Make Main or $db static. Then you can always access it through Main::$db